# Legend opacity in iPython Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am using the latest version of iPython Notebook in Python 3 to display plots using `%matplotlib inline`.  The legends in the plots have no background, the underlying figure shows through.  When I create the plots using the terminal or an IDE the legends are opaque.  How can I make the legends in the iPython Notebook opaque too?

```
py.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 8
py.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 8
py.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
py.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 12
py.rcParams['legend.fancybox'] = True
py.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True

py.figure(2, figsize=(14,6))

py.subplot(1,2,1)
py.plot(t, co, label='co')
py.plot(t, co2, label='co2')
py.plot(t, ch2o, label='ch2o')
py.plot(t, hcooh, label='hcooh')
py.plot(t, ch4, label='ch4')
py.plot(t, glyox, label='glyox')
py.plot(t, c2h4o, label='c2h4o')
py.title('Cellulose Species, T = {} K'.format(Tinf))
py.xlabel('Time (s)')
py.ylabel('Mass Fraction')
py.legend(loc='best', numpoints=1)

py.subplot(1,2,2)
py.plot(t, haa, label='haa')
py.plot(t, c3h6o, label='c3h6o')
py.plot(t, hmfu, label='HMFU')
py.plot(t, lvg, label='LVG')
py.plot(t, h2, label='h2')
py.plot(t, h2o, label='h2o')
py.plot(t, char, label='char')
py.title('Cellulose Species, T = {} K'.format(Tinf))
py.xlabel('Time (s)')
py.legend(loc='best', numpoints=1)

py.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

When you create your legend assign it to a variable, say `legend`, and then add these lines:

```
legend.get_frame().set_fc('w')
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(1)
legend.set_zorder(99)
```

This will make the background of the legend white and in front of the lines.

Comment: Adding just the `.get_frame().set_fc('white')` was enough to fix my problem.  Is it possible to apply this command in a code cell so it will be applied to every plot legend in the notebook?

Comment: As far as I can tell since `facecolor` parameter is not part of the `legend` `rc` section you can't set it up once per session. You would need to call it every time you need to change the legend for a plot.